# VSCode and Angular: auto- import/export/declarations a component from another module

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I've been using WebStorm for a while, but for some reason i decided to move to VSCode.
For the most part, everything suits me, except except for one problem.

If i create a module (for example, **core**) and create a component (for example, **header**) inside the "**core**" module, then when i try to use the component from "**core**" in "**app.component.html**" (**<app-header></app-header>**) i get compilation errors that disappear if i make a proper declaration of exports in "**core**" module and declarations in the "**app**" module.

In WebStorm, if i specify a component selector in the template, then everything happens by itself and i don't need to do it with my own hands. Even if i specifically delete the export of the component, a hint will appear to me, thanks to which i can fix everything.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same in VSCode?

Comment: So you want auto import/export components inside modules based on what is located inside the template files of a component? I've never seen that extension in vscode that does this